# Test for a Rails app

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd

Here's a test from a Rails app I'm working on. I want to know if I'm using `describe`, `let`, `before`, `expect`, etc in the proper way.

It is an integration test using `capybara` and `FactoryGirl`:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do
    subject {page}

    describe "profile page" do
        let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
        before do
            sign_in user
        end

        it { should have_selector('h1', text: user.name)}
        it { should have_selector('title', text: user.name)}

        describe "follow unfollow buttons" do
            let(:other_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}

            describe "following another user" do

                it "should increment the followed user count" do
                    visit user_path(other_user)
                    expect do
                        click_button "Follow"
                    end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(1)
                end

                it "should increment the other user's followers count" do
                    expect do
                        click_button "Follow"
                    end.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(1)
                end

                describe "toggling the button" do
                    before {click_button "Follow"}
                    it {should have_selector('input', value: 'Unfollow')}
                end
            end

            describe "unfollowing a user" do
                before do
                    user.follow!(other_user)
                    visit user_path(other_user)
                end

                it "should decrement the followed user count" do
                    expect do
                        click_button "Unfollow"
                    end.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(-1)
                end

                it "should decrement the other user's followers count" do
                    expect do
                        click_button "Unfollow"
                    end.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(-1)
                end

                describe "toggling the button" do
                    before { click_button "Unfollow"}
                    it{should have_selector('input', value: 'Follow')}
                end
            end
        end
    end
    describe "if logged in" do
        let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
        before do
            sign_in(user)
        end
        describe "it should have a tweet box" do
            describe "posting a message" do
                let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
                before {visit user_path(user.id)}
                subject {page}
                it {should have_selector("input", type: "text-field")}
            end
        end
        describe "on another users page" do
            let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            let(:other_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            before do
                sign_in user
                visit user_path(other_user)
            end
            subject{page}
            it "should follow user after clicking button and unfollow after that" do
                expect {click_button "Follow"}.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(1)
                expect {click_button "Unfollow"}.to change(other_user.followers, :count).by(-1)
                expect {click_button "Follow"}.to change(user.followed_user, :count).by(1)
                expect {click_button "Unfollow"}.to change(user.followed_users, :count).by(-1)
            end
        end
        describe "home page" do
            before do
                sign_in user
                visit "/users"
                click_link "Home"
            end
            it {page.should have_content "Your Timeline"}
        end
    end
    describe "if not logged in" do
        describe "on another users page" do
            let(:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            let(:other_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            before do
                visit user_path(other_user)
            end
            subject{page}
        end
    end

    describe "FollowUnfollows" do
        describe "Post to /relationships" do
            let (:other_user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            let (:user) {FactoryGirl.create(:user)}
            before do
                sign_in user
            end

            it "click Follow button" do
                visit user_path(other_user)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use contexts rather than describe on context.
2. make sure to keep the same depth with same contexts (story -> login_state -> page -> user_action)
3. dry your "let, subject, before"s

   ```
   subject { page }
   let (:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
   let (:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

   contexts "logged in" do
       before { sign_in user }

       describe "other user's profile page" do
           before {visit user_path(other_user.id)}
           ...
       end

       describe "profile page" do
           before {visit user_path(user.id)}
           ...
       end
       ...
   end

   contexts "logged out" do
       ...
   end
   ...
   ```